# why does 'rvm --default use 1.9.3' not set 1.9.3 as default?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have a multi-user rvm installation that I setup using the instructions from: https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Every time I go to the root directory of my application and run:

```
 rails s
```

The terminal complains with:

```
 The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
```

To fix this, I run:

```
 rvm use 1.9.3
```

or

```
 rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

The default is never set. The next time I go to the root directory of my app or even during the same session and open up a new terminal window to run 'rails c' I have to 'rvm use 1.9.3'... What did I miss? This is the second time I have setup a multi-user installation of rvm and had this happen. Its gone from annoying to frustrating.

Comment: I usually just put a file named `.ruby-version` in my project's root directory and in that file I put `1.9.3` (or whatever ruby version I want). Then any time I cd into that directory rvm will automatically change the ruby version for me. This is especially handy if you have multiple projects using different versions ruby.